# My Android app throws a RuntimeException

Tags: android, webview, connection, onresume

Android app gives me an error now:

```
package com.martijngijselaar.rooster;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebviewActivity extends MainActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }   

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if ( isOnline() == true )
            myWebView.loadUrl(webLink);
        else if ( isOnline() == false )
            showNoConnectionDialog();
    }
}
```

And this is the logcat:

> 11-25 12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-25
>   12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to resume activity
>   {com.martijngijselaar.rooster/com.martijngijselaar.rooster.WebviewActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 11-25 12:33:34.697:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
>   11-25 12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
>   11-25 12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
>   11-25 12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 11-25
>   12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   11-25 12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-25
>   12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 11-25 12:33:34.697:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 11-25
>   12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-25
>   12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 11-25 12:33:34.697:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   11-25 12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 11-25
>   12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-25 12:33:34.697:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(494): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 11-25
>   12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at
>   com.martijngijselaar.rooster.WebviewActivity.onResume(WebviewActivity.java:46)
>   11-25 12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
>   11-25 12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823) 11-25
>   12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
>   11-25 12:33:34.697: E/AndroidRuntime(494):    ... 12 more
>
> Blockquote

Comment: plz add the code that you have tried on your onResume method , did you add requestfeature() on it ?? if yes, so delete it , it is already added on your onCreate Method , or just , override the method onStart() ; and add the line requestfeature on it  , and delete it from the other methods  ( onCreate, onResume )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are really close. You just need to move the code that loads the url into onResume:

```
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
 if ( isOnline() == true )
            myWebView.loadUrl(webLink);
}
```

onResume is called right after onCreate so it will be called in both the case where it's the first load and when coming back from the pause.

Update based on discussion in the comments:
To move the web view to an instance variable:

```
public class WebviewActivity extends MainActivity {

  private WebView myWebView;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
     //the rest of your onCreate method here)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have one little question left, how do I get **myWebView.loadUrl(weblink);** available in the onResume? It says: myWebView cannot be resolved...

Comment: Declare mWebView as a class instance variable rather than a local (move the declaration outside the constructor method and put it right after your class declaration).

Comment: Can you maybe give me a short example? Thank you!

Comment: I added the example to my answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but it give me an error now... I did everything exactly as you said and it sais: **Unable to resume activity, java.lang.nullpointerexeption**... What dit I do wrong? It crashes on startup...

Comment: Can you update your question post with your updated code as well as the stack trace (or at least indicate which line is the cause of the NullPointerException)?

Comment: Remove this line from onCreate: WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);    and replace it with myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);  (notice i didn't declare a variable type).

Comment: Ah I just overlooked it, now it's working perfectly :) Thank you again!! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) flow.

Just leave the initializations in `onCreate` and check for the WIFI and launch dialog in onResume.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right creating all the stuff in the onCreate. onResume is executed when you turn on screen and device wakes up, so think about the logical stuff you should do then: refresh graphics which need to be refreshed, restart bluetooth or wifi communications if they were shut down, etc

Have a look at the schema of Activities lifecicles in Android Developers to learn how this works.